# Premature end of chunk coded message body: closing chunk expected

Tags: .net, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

Ошибка

```
org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of chunk coded message body: closing chunk expected
```

[image: [HttpGet] public IEnumerable<Book> Get()]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получаю только начало и не законченный массив. Использую:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: NuGet]

```
namespace MyLibraryOfBooks.Models{
public class Book{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? GenreId { get; set; }
    public virtual Genre Genre { get; set; }
}}

namespace MyLibraryOfBooks.Models{
public class Genre{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}}

namespace MyLibraryOfBooks.Models{
public class AppDatabaseContext : DbContext{
    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
    public AppDatabaseContext(){}
    public AppDatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<AppDatabaseContext> options) : base(options){
        Database.EnsureCreated())
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder){
        modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
            .HasOne(book => book.Genre)
            .WithMany(genre => genre.Books)
            .HasForeignKey(book => book.GenreId);
}}}

namespace MyLibraryOfBooks.Controllers{
[Route("[controller]")] 
public class BooksController : Controller{
    private readonly AppDatabaseContext _context;
    public BooksController(AppDatabaseContext context) { _context = context; }
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Book> Get(){
        return _context.Books.Include(book => book.Genre);  
    }
    [HttpGet("{id}"]
    public IIncludableQueryable<Book, Genre> Get(int id){
        return _context.Books.Where(book=>book.Id == id).Include(book =>book.Genre);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody] Book book){
        _context.Books.Add(book);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody] Book book){
        if (id != book.Id) return;
        _context.Entry(book).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public void Delete(int id){
        _context.Books.Remove(_context.Books.Find(id));
        _context.SaveChanges();
    } 
}}

namespace MyLibraryOfBooks.Controllers{
[Route("[controller]")]
public class GenresController : Controller{
    private readonly AppDatabaseContext _context;
    public GenresController(AppDatabaseContext context){
        _context = context;
    } 
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Genre> Get(){
        return _context.Genres.Include(genre => genre.Books);
    }
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public IQueryable<Genre> Get(int id){   
        var genre1=_context.Genres.Where(genre=>genre.Id == id).Include(genre=>genre.Books);
        return genre1;
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody] Genre genre){
        _context.Genres.Add(genre);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody] Genre genre){
        if (id == genre.Id) return;
        _context.Entry(genre).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public void Delete(int id){
        _context.Genres.Remove(_context.Genres.Find(id));
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }   
}}

namespace MyLibraryOfBooks{
public class Startup{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration){
        Configuration = configuration;
    }
    private IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
        services.AddCors(options =>{
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials());
            options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin", policy => policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5000"));
            options.AddPolicy("AllowGetMethod", policy => policy.WithMethods("GET"));
        });
        services.Configure < MvcOptions > (options => {  
            options.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory("CorsPolicy")); 
        });  
        services.AddDbContext<AppDatabaseContext>(options =>
            options.UseMySQL("server=localhost;port=3306;UserId=root;Password=;database=usersdb7;SslMode=none"));
        services.AddMvc();
    }
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env){
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
        if (env.IsDevelopment()){
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because EF Core will automatically fix-up navigation properties, you can end up with cycles in your object graph. For example, Loading a blog and it's related posts will result in a blog object that references a collection of posts. Each of those posts will have a reference back to the blog.

Some serialization frameworks do not allow such cycles. For example, Json.NET will throw the following exception if a cycle is encountered.

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop
>   detected for property 'Blog' with type 'MyApplication.Models.Blog'.

If you are using ASP.NET Core, you can configure Json.NET to ignore cycles that it finds in the object graph. This is done in the `ConfigureServices(...)` method in `Startup.cs`.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
...

services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(
        options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
    );

...
```

}

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#related-data-and-serialization